# Promedio en varias columnas en r

Tags: r

quiero sacar el promedio de varias columnas en r, por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
ID Moneda  Monto Monto_2   
A    MX      10     30
A    MX      10     15 
B    USD     20     10
B    USD     20     10
C    MX      40     50
```

Y a lo que quiero llegar es a lo siguiente

```
ID Moneda  Monto Monto_2   
A    MX     10    22.5
B    USD    20     10
C    MX     40     50
```

Muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.
Saludos,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una posible opción para lograr lo que buscas es usar el paquete dplyr

```
#Leemos los datos
df<-tibble::tribble(
~ID, ~Moneda,  ~Monto, ~Monto_2,   
"A",   "MX",      10,     30,
"A",    "MX",      10,     15,
"B",    "USD",     20,     10,
"B",    "USD",     20,     10,
"C",    "MX",      40,     50
)

#Instalar dplyr si es necesario
#install.packages(dplyr)

#cargar dplyr
library(dplyr)

#Calcular medias por grupos de todas las columnas
df%>%group_by(ID,Moneda)%>%
  summarise_all(mean)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [?]
  ID    Moneda Monto Monto_2
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A     MX        10    22.5
2 B     USD       20    10  
3 C     MX        40    50
```

Answer (score 2):

O si se prefiere la opción R base:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID + Moneda, df, mean)
```

Que se lee agrupar todo por `ID` y `Moneda` (`. ~ ID + Moneda`) y aplicar la función `mean`  a cada grupo.